# iCloud device login history

Tags: icloud, accounts

Is there any way you can find out which devices were previously logged in to your iCloud account even if they are no longer active? If they were removed directly in macOS’ iCloud app, would there be a way to find that information in syslog? Or does Apple provide that information?

Comment: Yes, you can.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345405/119271) for details on how to do this.