# Determining the date when an Apple ID was created

Tags: apple-id, ms-office, csv

I wish to determine when the date my Apple ID was created. To do that, I followed the instructions in this answer:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345405/279727

I am able to download an Excel file containing data corresponding to my Apple ID.
However, I am unable to parse the Create Date field. The field simply shows 38:05.0 in the **Create Date** column.

[image: Apple ID Account Information]

What could this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to open `Apple ID Account Information.csv` (the file you downloaded) in TextEdit first, to see the actual format of the "Create Date" column:

```
"123456789","j**************@me.com","2023-12-09 15:07:01.234","Mr","Joe","N/A","Doe" ...
```

After opening the CSV in Excel, right-click on column C, select "Format Cells..." and define a custom format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

[image]

PS: Numbers automatically detects/applies the correct formatting, so this may be the better option here.