# Need to prove an app was NOT on my iPhone on a given date

Tags: iphone, ios, logs, system-information

I’ve been accused by a professor of using one of my iPhone’s study apps during a test. The app by Instructure is called “Canvas Student.” Not only did I not cheat, this app that I allegedly used was not installed on my iPhone that day.

I have two back ups from that time period of my iPhone saved on my Mac: one using Apple Music and another using iMazing. Is there some way to show a comprehensive list of all the apps that were on my iphone on a particular day? I know that some apps are invasive and record activity of other apps. Is something like that possible in the logs?

I have looked in the logs, and I find many entries for the day in question. I just don’t know what I’m looking for.

Please help. My grade and school record are riding on this case.
Thank you.

Comment: What proof does the Professor has

Comment: It does probably not help you much, but: you do not have to prove anything. If they accuse you of cheating, they have to prove it. If they accuse you of cheating *with that particular app* they need to prove it.

Comment: @PhilippImhof is right. Even if you had the app installed, it doesn't mean you used it.

Comment: I doubt the backups would be helpful, since most backup apps allow you to specify exceptions that shouldn't be backed up. So a backup that doesn't include the app might be because you didn't back it up.

Comment: Did you *ever* install that app before the given day? If not, then this is easy to proof via the Purchases view of the App Store App (which includes free apps). If you *did* install it previously, but you had it uninstalled on that particular day... that's tougher.

Comment: @KrisVanBael You can still hide apps from your purchased view, iirc. And OP, you may need to start talking to higher up's at the school, like Deans, and get help taking care of this false accusation now, before the class is over and you've failed (or worse).

Comment: So during the test you are allowed to use your phone as long as it doesn't have this app installed? That's strange since you could cheat just using internet or sms. Are you completely sure the use of phones is allowed during the test? In most schools / universities using a phone during a test/exam results in an automatic failure, so having or not a particular app installed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 10):

You can try downloading your personal/private data activity report from https://privacy.apple.com.  I’ve written a similar answer (re: AppleId creation date) for the question [Determine the exact date of creation of an Apple ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/345401/119271).

That said, it’s important to note that there is a fundamental flaw with your professor’s assertion:  he’s asking you to prove a negative for something that isn’t tracked to begin with.  Try proving something that you didn’t do - can you prove that you *weren’t* at the sporting event , for example, you were told not to go to?

This data doesn’t exist.

We can learn if/when something was (un)installed but there’s no daily inventory taken of what’s currently there. You could have the app installed to test it out and uninstall it a couple hours later.  The fact it show up on the install log is not proof you cheated; it’s proof you installed it.

While I can’t advise you as to your next course of action should be with respect to this (get an advisor or lawyer), my *personal* approach would be remind the prof that if he believes I cheated, it’s his responsibility to provide proof of my guilt; I don’t need to prove my innocence.

Comment: I wanted to add this, but not as part of the official answer.  There is a [huge legal case](https://nypost.com/2023/09/17/former-yale-student-saifullah-khan-who-was-acquitted-of-rape-can-sue-accuser/) winding its way though the courts involving the expulsion of a student despite the defendant being aquitted by a jury and the school’s trial framing him quite falsely as a rapist.  While those charges are significantly more serious, schools should be on notice that they are leaving themselves liable for defamation.   It would be falsely labeling you a cheater in this case.  Talk to a lawyer!

Comment: You can prove you weren't at location X by providing evidence that you were at location Y at that time, i.e. an alibi. So that's not a good analogy for this situation.